# How do I deselect text in UITextView?

Tags: ios, uitextview

After some moment I need deselect text in UITextView.
How do I deselect text in UITextView?

[image]

EDIT:  I need to do programmatically.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`UITextView` adopts the `UITextInput` protocol, which has a `selectedTextRange` property.  Set the property to nil:

```
self.textView.selectedTextRange = nil;
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the way it works and you can touch wherever you want in the view in order to deselect the previously selected text:

On your UIViewController write this function:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you also call `super.touchesBegan(_:with:)`?

Answer (score 2):

The previous answer didn't work for me, the compiler complains:

> Sending 'void *' to parameter of incompatible type 'NSRange' (aka 'struct _NSRange')

I had to use an empty `NSRange` struct instead:

```
[self setSelectedRange:(NSRange){ .location = 0, .length = 0 }];
```

Comment: `selectedTextRange` is not the same as `selectedRange`.  That's why you got the error.