# UITextview selected text

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitextview

I've an UITabBarController. In my UIViewController a UItextView where I can select the text but when I change the View, text is kept selected. I've tried to add that code but doesn't work:

```
var range:NSRange = textView.selectedRange
range.length = 0
range.location = NSNotFound
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try setting `textView.selectedTextRange = nil`?

**Edit:** Depending on your requirements, could you set this in `viewWillDisappear` or `viewWillAppear` so it is deselected when you either leave or come back to your view controller?

Similar to: [How do I deselect text in UITextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9373938/how-do-i-deselect-text-in-uitextview)

Comment: If I stay in that `UIViewController` that work but if I change they kept that information.. I think `UITabBarController` save that data. @jday001

Comment: sorry if I didn't write before but I've already tried to write in `viewDidDisappear` and `viewWillDisappear` func, but it doesn't work..

Comment: is `textView` an `IBOutlet`?

Comment: and just to be sure, is the textView connected to the IBOutlet in the storyboard?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69693/discussion-between-mala-and-jday001).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69748/discussion-between-mala-and-jday).