# IOS UITextView How to remove the selected text

Tags: ios, uitextview

UITextView When input , like this how to get the selected text range,i need to remove the selected text.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQcj1.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[textView markedTextRange] & textView.textInputMode.primaryLanguage Would be useful

Answer (score 5):

Since [`UITextView`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextview) conforms to the [`UITextInput` protocol](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextinput), you can ask it for its [`selectedTextRange`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextinput/1614541-selectedtextrange), and then ask it to [replace](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextinput/1614558-replace) that range with an empty string:

```
if let range = textView.selectedTextRange {
    textView.replace(range, withText: "")
}
```

Comment: It's a text view, not a text field. It has a `selectedRange` property of its own.

Comment: [Yes, I know.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12990127/77567) If you think `selectedRange` is better for some reason, please post an answer showing how to use it to answer Y.Silient's question. I like my answer for two reasons. One, it works for `UITextField` too, so it's nice recipe to have in your cookbook. Two, I didn't have to test it to know it's correct. When the text view has no selection (not even an insertion point), `selectedTextRange` is nil. I don't know what `selectedRange` is under that circumstance so I'd have to run a test.

Comment: yes,selectedRange.length is nil.So there is no way I can get it